# Is there an IIS log viewer integrated into IIS Manager?

Tags: iis-7, logging

There are quite a few external IIS log analyzers but since IIS 7 has quite a nice administrative UI and new modules can be created for it, is there a module that would display / analyze log files directly from within IIS 7 Manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but there are several free and/or cheap options. One I would suggest is [Log Analyzer](http://www.welant.com/), affordable, and there is a trial as well.

Comment: @petrus Looks good to me.  Q: Is there an IIS log viewer integrated into IIS manager?  A: No.  It's correct too.